# How to use a logical function in a formula as text

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a column that contains `5`, `<10`, `>10` and `10`.

I am writing a countif formula and I want to count the cells that contains "<10", but Excel considers the "<" as a logical function. Therefore, the result is not correct.

The complete formula is:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(Master_tbl[Systemstatus],"*TABG*",Master_tbl[Klassen],"<10AT",Master_tbl[Erfassungsdatum],">=01.01.2017",Master_tbl[Erfassungsdatum],"<=31.01.2017",Master_tbl[Auftragsart],{"YAEL","YAFD","YALP","YAPL"},Master_tbl[IH-Leistungsart],{"T01"."T02"."T03"."T04"."T35"}))
```

and my challenge is `Master_tbl[Klassen],"<10AT"`

Is there any solution to bring the "<" in my formula as a normal character?

Thanks,
Dio

Comment: See if you find [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26877770/4604845) helpful

Comment: @Vegrad: That is actually my answer. Jerry in stackoverflow helped me with the similar solution, but just a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in stackoverflow, provided by Jerry.

Here it is: `Master_tbl[Klassen],"=<10AT"`

Here is the link of the answer: [answer in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47199714/how-to-use-a-logical-function-in-a-formula-as-text)